# ReWrite Rule to a URL Friendly Page and User Profile

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to use two RewriteRules to redirect Pages and Users to the right link but I'm coundn't achieve what I want, maybe someone could help me...

I want to redirect any Url Friendly page from:

```
http://www.example.com/my-url-friendly-page
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?cod=my-url-friendly-page
```

AND User Profiles from:

```
http://www.example.com/profile/username
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/profile/index.php?user=username
```

This is my htaccess, the first rule is working ok but I couldn't fix the second one...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?cod=$1
  RewriteRule ^/profile/(.*)$ index.php?user=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Can anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reorder your rules like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)$ index.php?user=$1 [QSA,L,NC]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?cod=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Can you explain why the Rules Order changed the results ?

Comment: If profile rules comes 2nd then other rules takes precedence since it is matching `.*` hence matching everything and causing profile rule to never execute.